# Stop webbrowser.open if graphical browser is not possible

Tags: python

Is it possible to stop webbrowser.open from opening a text-based browser if opening a graphical browser is not possible (e.g. running the script via SSH with no X-forwarding). I would prefer to display the link instead of relying on the text-based browser (needed javascript support, but unavailable in the text browser). This is my current code

```
import webbrowser
print(some_url)
webbrowser.open(some_url)
```

It would be nice if `webbrowser` can throw an exception if such case occurs, or even show what is the browser that it intends to open for `.open()` if an exception is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webbrowser module lists the text-based browsers it checks for, so you could just ignore them:

```
import webbrowser

def open_browser(url, new=0, autoraise=True, ignore=[]):
    for name in [b for b in webbrowser._tryorder if b not in ignore]:
        browser = webbrowser.get(name)

        if webbrowser.open(url, new, autoraise):
            return True

    return False

if not open_browser(url, ignore=['www-browser', 'links', 'elinks', 'lynx', 'w3m']):
    print('Go to', url)
```

A hackier method would be to monkey patch `os.environ`:

```
import os
import webbrowser

def open_browser(url, new=0, autoraise=True, ignore_console=False):
    if not ignore_console:
        return webbrowser.open(url, new, autoraise)

    original_get = os.environ.get

    def new_get(self, key, failobj=None):
        if key == 'TERM':
            return failobj

        return original_get(self, key, failobj)

    try:
        os.environ.get = new_get
        return webbrowser.open(url, new, autoraise)
    finally:
        os.environ.get = original_get
```